# Outlook renders HTML tags differently compared to other mail client

Tags: email, outlook

I have created an email template for our site. When I look that email template in outlook 2013, I'm getting collapsed layout. But, I'm getting expected email template in other mail clients like gmail, etc.

I'm aware, outlook renders using "Microsoft word engine", but i couldn't figure out where i go wrong with my code. Here is the code i have used

```
.header img{
     margin-left: 25px !important;
     margin-top: 46px !important; 
     vertical-align: center; 
}
.footer-social-links{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't recognize `margin` with a lowercase m. Furthermore it has buggy support for margin. As an example, there's no support for `margin-top`.

- https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/margin/

For a top margin replacement, consider using `line-height` or a spacer table.

Good luck.